# SwiftUI three column navigation layout not closing when selecting same item

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm using a three column navigation layout and facing the issue, that when selecting the same second column's item, the drawers won't close. If I take the files app as reference, selecting the same item again will close the drawer. Can someone tell me what's the issue? And is `drawer` the correct term?

Code to reproduce:

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension UISplitViewController {

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        preferredDisplayMode = .twoBesideSecondary
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {

    @Environment(\.factory) var factory

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView(viewModel: factory.createVM1())
                ContentView2(viewModel: factory.createVM2())
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FactoryKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Factory = Factory()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {

    var factory: Factory {
        get {
            return self[FactoryKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[FactoryKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

class Factory {
    func createVM1() -> ViewModel1 {
        ViewModel1()
    }

    func createVM2() -> ViewModel2 {
        ViewModel2()
    }

    func createVM3(from item: ViewModel2.Model) -> ViewModel3 {
        ViewModel3(item: item)
    }
}

class ViewModel1: ObservableObject {

    struct Model: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let name: String
    }

    @Published var items: [Model]

    init() {
        items = (1 ... 4).map { Model(name: "First Column Item \($0)") }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.factory) var factory

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel1

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ContentView2(viewModel: factory.createVM2()),
                    label: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel2: ObservableObject {

    struct Model: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let name: String
    }

    @Published var items: [Model]

    init() {
        items = (1 ... 4).map { Model(name: "Second Column Item \($0)") }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {

    @Environment(\.factory) var factory
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel2

    var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Detail(viewModel: factory.createVM3(from: item)),
                    label: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel3: ObservableObject {
    let item: ViewModel2.Model

    init(item: ViewModel2.Model) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct Detail: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel3

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.item.name)
    }
}
```